# Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: null

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I've been trying to embed this map into my react app but can't seem to figure out what the issue is here. I tried to change the import syntax by adding {} around certain packages but it didn't seem to fix the issue. I'm relatively new to React and would greatly appreciate any help!

Map.js

```
import React from 'react';
import {StyleSheet, Text, View } from 'react-native';
import MapView  from 'react-native-maps';

class Map extends React.Component{
  constructor(props)  {
      super(props);

      this.state = {
        region: {
          latitude: 37.78825,
          longitude: -122.4324,
          latitudeDelta: 0.922,
          longitudeDelta: 0.0421,
        }
      }
    }
  render() {
    return (
      <View style = {styles.container}>
        <Text>HomeScreen</Text>
        <MapView
          initialRegion = {this.state.region}
          showsUserLocation = {true}
          showsCompass = {true}
          rotateEnabled = {false}
          style = {{flex: 1}}
        />
      </View>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: '#fff',
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
  },
});

export default Map;
```

EDIT: This is where I imported Map

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { createBottomTabNavigator } from '@react-navigation/bottom-tabs';
import TabBarIcon from '../components/TabBarIcon';
import HomeScreen from '../screens/HomeScreen';
import LinksScreen from '../screens/LinksScreen';
import LockScreen from '../screens/LockScreen';
import Map from '../screens/Map';

const BottomTab = createBottomTabNavigator();
const INITIAL_ROUTE_NAME = 'Home';
```

Comment: add import statement of `Map`

Comment: Is the import of `MapView` working? Can you confirm that you are not getting `null` for that? Test with `console.log(MapView)`.

Comment: can you share where are you importing your `Map` component?

Comment: I logged the value for MapView and it says its not defined but I think it's only saying that since the react app broke